# Helm Chart restrict values that can be overridden

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am trying to build a chart and define parameters with default values in values.yaml file. I want to restrict the parameters which can be overridden. Is there any way to do it. Current i am able to override all parameters in values.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

You can just hardcode the values in the respective files in templates directory & don't define that value in the `values.yaml` file at all.